# CSS Flexbox Not Floating to Right

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I am struggling with `flexbox` and am looking for some help getting my navbar up and running.

I have the following code that should have my logo + title on the left of the navbar and a menu of options on the right side. Any idea why my flexbox is all left justified and the `item--4` is not floating over to the right?

```css
.flex-container {
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
}

.flex-item {
  background: orangered;
  color: white;
}

.flex-item--4 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin-left: auto;
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">
      <a class="navbar-brand" style="padding-left: 20px;" href="{% if user.is_staff or user.is_superuser %}{% url 'admin:index' %}{% else %}{% url 'app:home' %}{% endif %}">
        <img src="{% static 'img/bootstrap-solid.svg' %}" width="21" height="21" alt="Logo" class="mr-2 mt-n1"> Title
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item--4">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDarkDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        Hello {{ request.user.get_full_name|default:request.user }}!
                        </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark" aria-labelledby="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLink">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">About</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Account</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a></li>
              <li>
                <hr class="dropdown-divider">
              </li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'account:logout' %}"> Sign Out</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `flex-grow: 1` to your `flex-item--4` element means it expands to fill the available space. There is no space remaining for the margin to take up.

Remove `flex-grow: 1`, and the element will be pushed to the right-hand side.

For some reason, I also had to add `width:100%` to the `flex-container` - I'm assuming a Bootstrap style is limiting the width.

```css
.flex-container {
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.flex-item {
  background: orangered;
  color: white;
}

.flex-item--4 {
  margin-left: auto;
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">
      <a class="navbar-brand" style="padding-left: 20px;" href="{% if user.is_staff or user.is_superuser %}{% url 'admin:index' %}{% else %}{% url 'app:home' %}{% endif %}">
        <img src="{% static 'img/bootstrap-solid.svg' %}" width="21" height="21" alt="Logo" class="mr-2 mt-n1"> Title
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item--4">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse show" id="navbarNavDarkDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        Hello {{ request.user.get_full_name|default:request.user }}!
                        </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark" aria-labelledby="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLink">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">About</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Account</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a></li>
              <li>
                <hr class="dropdown-divider">
              </li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'account:logout' %}"> Sign Out</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `width: 100%;` to have it full width, and `flex-grow: 0` to the menu to *not*  let it fill the remaining space, but right-align. `margin-auto: left` already does the right alignment.

```css
.flex-container {
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.flex-item {
  background: orangered;
  color: white;
}

.flex-item--4 {
  flex-grow: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">
      <a class="navbar-brand" style="padding-left: 20px;" href="{% if user.is_staff or user.is_superuser %}{% url 'admin:index' %}{% else %}{% url 'app:home' %}{% endif %}">
        <img src="{% static 'img/bootstrap-solid.svg' %}" width="21" height="21" alt="Logo" class="mr-2 mt-n1"> Title
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item--4">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDarkDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        Hello {{ request.user.get_full_name|default:request.user }}!
                        </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark" aria-labelledby="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLink">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">About</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Account</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a></li>
              <li>
                <hr class="dropdown-divider">
              </li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'account:logout' %}"> Sign Out</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```